# Python - How to sort a text file based on date time stamp on a column

Tags: python, sorting, indexing

I have a text file below:

```
asd|2016-03-17 14:33:05|asd|
asd|2017-03-17 14:27:25|asd|
asd|2016-03-15 14:27:25|asd|
asd|2016-03-17 14:33:05|asd|
asd|2016-03-16 14:33:05|asd|
```

I tried the code below but I am getting "IndexError: string index out of range" error.

```
with open(file) as inf:
    for line in inf:
        data = line.split('|')
        sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda line: line[1])
```

Desired Output: I want to sort the text file using the second column delimited by '|' and output it to another file.

Answer (score 2):

As your date format is already sortable, you don't need to use `datetime`, and can simplify this all down to

```
lines = sorted( open(file).readlines(), key=lambda line: line.split("|")[1])
```

Or if you want to keep it simple in terms of number of ops per line

```
lines = open(file).readlines()
lines.sort(key=lambda line: line.split("|")[1])
```

**NB** `list.sort` is an **in-place** operation.

Finally, e.g.

```
with open('outfile', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write("\n".join(lines))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're applying sorting on each line, rather then all lines collectively. You need to read the file in a list, and then sort it rather:

```
>>> inf = open(file)
>>> lines = inf.readlines()
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
>>> sorted_lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda line: datetime.strptime(line.split("|")[1], format))
>>> sorted_lines
['asd|2016-03-15 14:27:25|asd|\n', 'asd|2016-03-16 14:33:05|asd|\n', 'asd|2016-03-17 14:33:05|asd|\n', 'asd|2016-03-17 14:33:05|asd|\n', 'asd|2017-03-17 14:27:25|asd|\n']
```

You can write the new list to a file afterwards.